# TextField's input text cutting in half after getting full?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

> [Screenshot of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eSRpp.jpg)

I am trying to add an Email, which is a long text, but when the text field got full it cut all text in half.
here is my code:

```
        Container(
            height: 45,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: HexColor(MyColors.white),
            ),
            child: TextFormField(
            controller: _email,
            maxLength: 100,                        
           autofocus: true,
           validator: validateEmail,
           keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
           decoration: InputDecoration(
           labelText: 'Email',
           counterText: "",
           border: OutlineInputBorder(),
          ),
         ),
       ),
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I get your point.. your problem there is text got high up.. you can set

Just adjust the contentPadding top bottom so it can be centered

````
decoration: InputDecoration(
                 contentPadding:
                  const EdgeInsets.only(
                  left: 8.0,
                  bottom: 8.0,
                  top: 8.0)),```
````

Comment: decoration: InputDecoration(
            contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
), fixed the issue for me

Answer (score 8):

My problem get solved by adding those lines:

```
 maxLines: 1,
 decoration: InputDecoration(
              isDense: true,
              .
              .
              .)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem happens because you are using `Container` in the wrong way, so your `Container` is covering your `TextFormField`. So, in my opinion you can use `Container`, but with minimal attribute, or without attributes at all. But, I'm more prefer to not using `Container`.

And also, you can add the `maxLines` as `null` if you want it to be really long.

Your code should be like:

```
TextFormField(
            maxLines: null,
            controller: _email,
            maxLength: 100,
            autofocus: true,
            validator: validateEmail,
            keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              labelText: 'Email',
              counterText: "",
              border: OutlineInputBorder(),
            ),
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.black,
            ),
          ),
```

Also, you can improve the design later by your self.
(NOTE: In my codes, I'm not using `Container`)

Comment: Actually, the default height of the text field is bigger than I want, so, to make the height smaller, I have to use a container or a size box. Even after removing the container, the text is still cutting in half.

Comment: Hmm, that's weird. I've successfully made the `TextFormField` to not cut in half.